# Canvas Element Does Not Work in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an issues is transferring the animated  code and it's scripts over to the new development site.

Here's a working copy that is not using Wordpress: [Working Canvas](http://apriva.vps101156.mylogin.co/test/CANVASes.html)

You can view the source code to what scripts are being used.

So I applied that same code to Wordpress press and it simply does not show up. Here's the link: [Non-Functioning Canvas](http://apriva.vps101156.mylogin.co/_canvas/)

Again, if you view that source code you will find the same scripts starting around line 311.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Script placement? Conflict with another script?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Open devtools. You have an error. It looks like the URL you're using to load jQuery is returning a 404

Comment: I believe I have corrected that now. It now shows up as expected but only when you are logged into Wordpress.  Once I log out, it quits working.  Why do you think that is?

Comment: Update:  The error I get is from the home-animiation.js script.  But I do not understand what's wrong:
$(document).ready(function() {
    init('shield', '529F8C0DE727C242B84D64320109BCF9');
    init('main', '3D59302609746446B9EC6A7092DF1D76');
    init('solutions', '96FAB19924FC574BABEF083578DED3D6');
    init('platform', 'B3B3310CEC92D649A28EDFA8C6BB3A1E');
});

Answer (score 0):

After making various changes to the jquery file, I never could get it to work.  When someone pointed out that the html and scripts were missing or could not be found in the source, I revisited that area to make sure that was the case and I could never figure out why it was missing.  After doing a compare between being logged in versus being logged out, the canvas code showed up and works when I am logged in. However, when not logged in, both the canvas code and the related scripts did not appear in the source at all. I said, "Why NOT?"

After yanking a few more strands of hair from my head, I finally figured out that it was one of the widgets for Elementor page builder.  Initially, I used the 'Custom HTML' widget to display those canvases and scripts. So I looked to see if there were another similar widget I could use and sure enough there was one called 'HTML'.  Once I moved all my codes over to that widget, my animated canvas code start to work. Yeah!!!

I would appreciate anyone here to view [this link](http://apriva.vps101156.mylogin.co/) to verify that it is working for you too.

Thank you.